# couchbase filtering multiple fields

Tags: couchbase

I’m trying to work out the best way to filter multiple fields in CouchBase when the values I’m filtering on aren’t contiguous. For example, if I had a table called **Product** with these fields:

- ProductId
- CategoryId
- ProductTypeId
- Price

And I’m trying to achieve a filter like this:

```
SELECT  * FROM Product WHERE CategoryID IN (1,5,7) AND ProductTypeId
IN (10, 12);
```

Is the best way to do this to have a view for each field, run the IN as the query using keys (e.g. `by_categoryId?keys=[1,5,7]`) and then insersect the results in application code? Or is there a better way to do this? (I don’t think I can use a range query as the array elements would not be contiguous).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In couchbase simple views can have only one index, so you can't filter by 2 or more fields using it. There is also spatial views in couchbase that have 2-dimentional index, but

> Geospatial support was introduced as an experimental feature in Couchbase Server 2.0. This feature is currently unsupported and is provided only for the purposes of demonstration and testing.

So first variant: Get records from couchbase filtered by one field that produce less results and then on app-side you can filter results by another field.

Second variant: You can create pairs like "CategoryID:ProductTypeID" (i.e. `1:10, 1:12, 5:10, 5:12, 7:10, 7:12`) on app-side and create view that generates that pairs too (i.e. `emit(doc.catId + ":" + doc.prodTypeId)`) and query it.

Third variant (preferred by me): Use relational database for it. I count 3 relations in your `Product` with 4 fields - it's 75%, you've got relational datamodel! And NoSQL definition is [Next Generation Databases mostly addressing some of the points: being non-relational, distributed, open-source and horizontally scalable](http://www.nosql-database.org/). Or may be you can change your datamodel...

Answer (score 0):

You can use new N1Q1 query language from Couchbase (v3). You can express all your "WHERE" conditions in the query without having any view created.

Try online [N1QL tutorial](http://query.pub.couchbase.com/tutorial)

Comment: While this will be the correct answer in the future, N1QL is not in the current version of couchbase server. Hopefully the secondary index feature that will come with N1QL will help solve this problem as well.